# zWeatherFeed options?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, weather, yahoo-weather-api

I used zWeatherFeed to show weather, but I cant find any example to change options.

```
<style>
    .weatherItem{padding-left:200px;}
    .odd{height:130px;}
    .weatherCity{font-weight:bold;}
    .weatherFeed{height: 130px; width: 100%;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#test').weatherfeed(['TUXX0015']);
    });
</script>
<div id="test">
</div>
```

For example I want to show next day too. Is there any example about this weather plugin or any alternative weather plugin? I prefer to use zWeatherFeed because This plugin has great visualization.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The zWeatherFeed plugin is not able to show the next day's forecast at present (although provides a link for a full forecast). The available options are:

- unit - Specifies the units to return: 'c' - celsius, 'f' - fahrenheit
- image - If true, displays an image of the weather condition in the
  background.
- highlow - If true, includes the high and low values in each item.
- wind - If true, includes the wind direction and strength in each
  item.
- link - If true, includes the link to full forecast on the Yahoo!
  website.
- showerror - If true, displays a message if the feed is unavailable or
  the location is invalid.
- linktarget - Specifies the target for forecast links ('_blank',
  '_self', '_top', framename).
- woeid - If true, uses Yahoo! WOEID indentifiers for locations

http://www.zazar.net/developers/jquery/zweatherfeed/

Answer (score 0):

`<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#weatherDiv').weatherfeed(['EIXX0048'], {
            forecast: true
        });
    });
</script>`

If you add the option 
forecast:true
to the options for the function and it will show the forecast for the next 5 days. An full example can be seen at:
http://www.zazar.net/developers/jquery/zweatherfeed/example_forecast.html